# Split large json file and assign each part to a process

Tags: python, json, parsing, multiprocessing

I am trying to refine a large JSON data set ~ 14 GiB (12 Million lines) with multiple processes, so that i can be faster. I created two  `multiprocessing.Queue` instances, `in_q` and `out_q`. They would read the data in the `data-2021-09-29.jsonl` file (it's the data set), and output the line that contains the data that I am interested in and write it into another file `stokes_DE_file.jsonl` (This is the part where i am refining the data set, the output file is the refined version of the data set). I have 16 CPUs on my machine, let's say I want to split the file in 16 parts, the number of lines would be the variable LINES_PER_PROCESS. How can I assign to each process one part of the file ? Following is the code that I've written so far.
Just starting with multiprocessing module in python. Here's my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import json
import reverse_geocoder as rg

LINES_PER_PROCESS = 12137928/(mp.cpu_count()-1)

def geocode_worker(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        strike = in_q.get()
        if strike is None:
            out_q.put(None)
            return
        strike_location = (strike['lat'], strike['lon'])
        if rg.search(strike_location)[0]['cc'] == 'DE':
            out_q.put('{}\n'.format(strike))

def file_write_worker(out_q, fileobj, worker_count):
    while worker_count:
        for msg in iter(out_q.get, None):
            
            if msg is None:
                worker_count -= 1
            fileobj.write(msg)

def get_germany_strokes(jsonl_file):
    
    worker_count = mp.cpu_count() - 1
    in_q, out_q = mp.Queue(), mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=geocode_worker, args=(in_q, out_q)) for _ in range(worker_count)]
    
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
        
    with open('strokes_DE_file.json', newline='') as strokes_DE_file:
        file_writer = threading.Thread(target=file_write_worker, args=(out_q, strokes_DE_file, worker_count))
        file_writer.start()
        
    with open(jsonl_file, newline='') as file:
        next(file)
        for line in file:
            strokes = json.loads(line)['strokes']
            for strike in strokes:
                in_q.put(strike)
                    
get_germany_strokes('data-2021-09-29.jsonl')
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your question is vague, we don't know what exactly you need without knowing what error/exception/issue you are trying to solve as of now.

Comment: My question is: How can I split the file in let's say 15 Parts and assign each part to a process so that each process can filter the data that he's been assigned and write it to an output file.

Comment: Is your data a list of jsons or a very big json? It's important.

Comment: Anyway your can see this: https://github.com/kashifrazzaqui/json-streamer it helps you stream your json file. Read every N objects you find feasible, and then process those N objects using multiprocessing. I would also suggest using a simple `multiprocessing.Pool` instance with one of the `pool.map` variants.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is splitting my data set with the `split -l` command in Linux and specifying the number of lines per subset. I assigned each subset to a process, in total 15 processes is approximately the optimal number of processes to create (considering the overhead/load balancing).